# Merge or synonymize request: [powershell-core] and [powershell-6.0]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Actually Microsoft changed naming several times and right now they called it [Microsoft Powershell Core 6.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/)

Both tags contain no questions right now so it is better to put things in order right now.

My suggestion is to merge [powershell-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) to [powershell-6.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-6.0).  In the [official repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/Powershell) both names are being used interchangeably, in the [reference documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-core-support?view=powershell-6) **Powershell 6** seems to be preferred variant.

Please vote for answers below and/or provide your alternative as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> My suggestion is to merge PowerShell-core to PowerShell-6.0. In the official repository, both names are being used interchangeably, in the reference documentation, Powershell 6 seems to be the preferred variant.

In my opinion, we should just delete `PowerShell-Core`, and keep it `PowerShell-6.0` which matches `PowerShell-5.0`.  This would match tags like Visual Studio, C# (at SO), Office, Windows.  We can use a tag description within 6.0/6.1 to indicate it's also called `PowerShell Core 6.x`.

In any event, only a single question has used the tags in question, so we could simply edit that single question and remove the erroneous tag that was created.

We could then make `PowerShell Core 6.x` a synonym with `PowerShell-6.0`, although the same would have to be done with `PowerShell-6.1` and `PowerShell Core 6.x`, so I think simply removing `PowerShell Core 6.0` might be the better option.

**A tag merger seems a little overkill for a tag that has been used once.**  `PowerShell-6.0`is the tag that has had a description written for it, a single person, erroneously created the `PowerShell Core 6.0` tag.  It has no description currently.

Answer (score 1):

Merge [powershell-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) and [powershell-6.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Make powershell-core a synonym of powershell-6.0:

[powershell-core](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-core) → [powershell-6.0](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell-6.0)